# Mariadb replaced by MySQL by Yum Ugrade

Tags: mariadb

Yum Upgrade is replacing installed mariadb Server with MySQL Community Server in CentOS 7 (after the usual "is it OK?" question if "Y" is selected)
While CentOS 7 installation is forced to install mariadb as the database; later on the enforcement is undone by the "yum upgrade". I did not try "yum update" yet to see if it does too.

Comment: Yes, MariaDB forked from MySQL and same myql but community-base and has bug less than mysql. refer to difference between community-base and company-base....